# How would i recreate this standard equalizer layout in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm currently working on a simple equaliser to expand my knowledge on how good layouts are created and the right way in which to implement them. What i'm trying to achieve here are 5 vertical `SeekBars` accompanied by 3 `TextViews` that will fall into a Child Layout. There will be 5 of these Child Layout's in total that fall under the Parent Layout.

Here's a quick demonstration i drew up...

[image]

I'm not very familiar with how android layouts work, so im hoping that this will help me and others learn how to compose layouts properly, which i can then use to move into more advanced territory.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xml use  android:layout_weight tag :

You can use this library

https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-verticalseekbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llCamera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:text="xx"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="xx"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="150dp">
    <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
      android:id="@+id/mySeekBar"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:seekBarRotation="CW90" /> <!-- Rotation: CW90 or CW270 -->
   </com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper>


    <TextView
        android:text="xx"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me the basis of it, but what about the vertical seekbar? And also, would i need to encapsulate this in the Child Layout?

Comment: Adding a vertical seek bar is the real deal. I used my own custom vertical seek bar in a recycler view to make an equalizer. You can use the existing seekBar in vertical but arranging the layout can get real tricky.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't render the `android:rotation="270"` line in design mode, so i only know the outcome of the code when i run it. Very time consuming and tricky to get right.